# How to open an app without redirecting the page

Tags: javascript

I currently have a button. When it's clicked I execute a javascript code.

```js
var openAppBtn = document.getElementById("openAppBtn");
openAppBtn.onclick = function () {

    var app = {
        launchApp: function () {
            window.location.replace("testappscheme://")
        }      
    };

    app.launchApp();
};
```

```html
<a id="openAppBtn" class="btn" href="">Open KWCP App</a>
```

when I execute this bit of code on iOS, the page does a refresh if the app is not installed. May I ask how do I attempt to open the app without the page redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe to trigger the app intent. Example code for triggering the intent on the page-load for example. Just put it inside your click function.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
  frame.src = 'testappscheme:/' + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
  frame.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(frame);

  // the following is optional, just to avoid an unnecessary iframe on the page
  setTimeout(function() { document.body.removeChild(frame); }, 4);
</script>
```

Simply by clicking the button, add an iframe to your page with the schema-url.

Comment: Didn't end up using this approach. Was too overly complicated for something so simple. Changed it to be a button and it worked like a charm.